# In Vim, how to make commands like gg, dG work in one line?

Tags: vim

I often do these commands together:

"gg, dG, i, shift+insert" (to replace everything to my clipboard text)

I feel like something absolutely can be combined together. I'm not quite following the vim functions instruction.

Is it possible to do something with ':gg dG i...' like? So whenever I type ":" editor mode, I can use up arrow key to use the last command i used.

Comment: I tried 'gg, yG', it doesn't really copy from my clipboard but doing a separate yank which looks from vim itself.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine the various commands in a map, for example `gy`:

```
nnoremap gy ggdGi<c-r>+<esc>
```

This copies the contents of the clipboard register (`:help "+`)

Comment: Thanks! Yours by far works the best but it stopped at ggdG without going into insert mode and paste.

Comment: In the map, could you try  replacing `+` with  `*` and check if it works?

Comment: nope,  nnoremap gy ggdGi<c-r>*<esc> - still stop at G.

Comment: This would be better as `:%delete | put +<CR>`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, it deleted everything but gives error " Invalid Register Name", without paste my clipboard stuff.

Comment: @TonyYun then try `put *`—the `<CR>` is for the mapping, not to type if doing it yourself

Comment: still the same error. no insert mode, no paste. I more tend to make git pull methods now to copy the files now..

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ggdG"*p
```

See [bullet 7](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote_=) about registers `"*` and `"+`. Try one or the other.